# How to set the scroll position of a WPF RichTextBox to view a specific word or line

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I want to write a TTS program that automatically scrolls to the spoken word.
I found a [solution for paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666318/how-to-set-the-scroll-position-of-a-richtextbox-by-behind-code-in-wpf-for-every). I am not using paragraphs, but I adapt this solution to use the `characterIndex` of the current word:

```
        TextPointer startTextRange = richtTextselectionView.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(characterIndex);
        verticalOffset = startTextRange.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward).Y;
        richtTextselectionView.ScrollToVerticalOffset(verticalOffset);
```

This is the Result:

[image: GIF of the current Program code. The scroll speed is too slow, and the viewport only reaches until eight instead of twelve]

The Problem is that the text box is scrolling too slow.

I already tried to multiply the `verticalOffset` with a constant but the behavior seems to be nonlinear...

I am using .Net6.0 and [MaterialDesignThemes](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) in the latest version.

Comment: Yes, I allow text input. 
I just used one, two, three as an example to demonstrate the problem. 
And yes, I would be also fine with a normal TextBox, but I couldn't find a good solution to highlight the spoken words.